# Is there a way to let the "<", ">" keys work in a Keyman keyboard?

Tags: keyman, keyman-developer

I created an Esperanto keyboard, using the [Keyman Developer](https://keyman.com/windows/download) program, for the italian language, that works very fine, with the exceptions of the "<", ">" keys, which no longer work, though I wrote no code about these two keys. The keyboard allows you to write special Esperanto characters "ĉĝĥĵŝŭĈĜĤĴŜŬ", by typing "x" or "X" after the letters "cghjsuCGHJSU". Here is my code:

```
store(&version) '15.0'
store(&mnemoniclayout) "1"
store(&targets) 'desktop'

begin Unicode > use(main)

group(main) using keys

store(i_xchars) "cghjsuCGHJSU"
store(o_xchars) "ĉĝĥĵŝŭĈĜĤĴŜŬ"
store(x_stroke) "xX"

any(i_xchars) + any(x_stroke) > index(o_xchars, 1)
```

I tried also with `store(&mnemoniclayout) "0"`

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should use virtual key references rather than character references with `store(&mnemoniclayout) "0"`. I assume the key you are having problems with is the key to the left of the `Z` key. If so this can be targeted by `+ [K_oE2] > '<'` and `+ [SHIFT K_oE2] > '>'` or in the latest keyman: `+ [B00] > '<'` and `+ [SHIFT B00] > '>'`.